# Xamarin: What IntentFilter to use for Wifi HotSpot

Tags: android, xamarin, android-wifi, access-point

I wanted to check to see whether the device enable Wifi AP. I am currently using Connectivity_Action as an intentfilter but it receive all the connectivity status. Is there an intentFilter specifically for determined Wifi AP enabled/disabled?

I am looking for WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED in xamarin but I couldn't find it. I think this intent filter can solve my issue.

Comment: I am currently using xamarin so I am looking for WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED equivalent on xamarin.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Net.Wifi.WifiManager.WifiStateChangedAction/

Answer (score 0):

#### Available states:

```
public enum  WifiApState
{
    WIFI_AP_STATE_UNKNOWN = -1,
    WIFI_AP_STATE_DISABLING = 0,
    WIFI_AP_STATE_DISABLED = 1,
    WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLING = 2,
    WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLED = 3,
    WIFI_AP_STATE_FAILED = 4
}
```

#### Android.Net.WifiState:

- WifiState.Disabled
- WifiState.Disabling
- WifiState.Enabled
- WifiState.Enabling
- WifiState.Unknown

#### Sample:

```
var wm = Android.Net.Wifi.WifiManager;
var ws = wm.WifiState;
```

Ref: [WifiManager | Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)

Ref: [Android.Net.Wifi.WifiManager Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Net.Wifi.WifiManager/)

Comment: Isn't that only applied to Wifi not the WifiAp